# Is there ever a reason to use `cat` when you've got `less`?

Tags: less, cat

I used to use `cat` to view files. Then I learned that `less` is usually better, and is a must if the file is longer than a few dozen rows.

My question: Is there ever a reason to use `cat` instead of `less`? Is there any situation where `cat` is a better solution?

Comment: `less` and `cat` solve different problems and they are each better than the other in their own problem domain

Comment: I only use `cat` to pipe it's output into `less` afterwards.

Comment: I often use `cat` to print very short files to the console, the files in `/proc` and `/sys` are very good candidates. This way I can see the content of multiple files simultaneously.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I personally prefer `view` for static content or `tail -f` for dynamic content.

This does not answer your question, though. There is a saying "why use more if you have less" ;-)

But there are cases where I prefer cat to less:
I usually work with X11-windows. These windows have a scroll-buffer which can be set to some hundred lines.

Doing a `cat` for - let's say 200 lines and then using the mouse with the scroll-bar is more comfortable to me than using `less` in these cases.

Comment: By `view` you mean the usual `vim -R`, or you have something else with that name?

Comment: No - just vi (or vim) in read-only-mode. CentOS sets that alias by default. This will not trigger HIDS when viewing a file in a secured directory.

Comment: `less +F` does what `tail -f` does.

Comment: Actually, `view` is not an alias; it's a link (to `vi` or `vim`). `vi` looks at `argv[0]` when it starts (to see what name it was invoked under) and, if that is `view` or `rview`, it sets read-only mode (as if you had typed `vim -R`).

Answer (score 104):

Although both commands allow you to view the content of a file, their original purposes are quite different.

less extends the capabilities of [more](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?more). The latter was created to view the content of a file one screenful at a time. less adds features such as backward movements and better memory management (no need to read the entire file before being able to see the first lines).

cat concatenates files and prints the result on the standard output. If you provide only one file, you will see the content of that file. It becomes 'powerful' when you provide multiple files. A good example is the combination of [split](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?split) and cat. The first command will divide a large file in small portions. The second one will then concatenate the small portions into a single file.

Back to your question, cat would be preferred in an autonomous script requiring files to be read entirely (or concatenated) without interaction. In terms of file viewing, I think it's more a question of taste.

Comment: `less` always allows to search within the file, which `cat` does not.

Comment: @Bernhard: What about doing a grep on cat output?

Answer (score 26):

I usually use `cat` when I need to type a command based on something in the file. `cat` is more convenient since you can see the file (if it's small) while you have access to the shell prompt. It also allows for pipe lining.

Comment: For one file, redirecting the standard input is also possible and often preferable.

Answer (score 18):

> Is there any situation where cat is a better solution?

When you are dealing with more that one file and wish to concatenate them.

From the man page:

```
cat f - g
        Output f's contents, then standard input, then g's contents.
```

Answer (score 18):

There are people who argue violently that the only purpose of `cat` is to con*cat*enate files. For every other use, there is `more` (or `less`).

But this fails to take into account one quite important fact: **`cat` is one character less to type.** I use those commands so often that one character less is a no-brainer.

**Another reason is when you want to create a file.** I often copy-and-paste text from the web into a file like this (command prompt shown):

```
$ cat > filename
<Cmd-V>
<Ctrl-D>
$
```

That is, I open a file `filename` for write access, paste the content and close the stream by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>. Neither `less` nor `more` can do that, and it’s faster than opening an editor.

Comment: If you use zsh as a shell, you can set it up so that `$<filename` (where `$` is the prompt) invokes $PAGER with stdin connected to `filename`. That is even fewer characters to type than `cat`.

Comment: @Kevin Nice to know but I’m a bash user.

Comment: On Mac OS X, I use `pbpaste > filename`, and I believe X has something similar. I do still use `cat` for quick file creation, just not for pasting.

Comment: @cobbal Hehe, I never thought of that even though I use `pbcopy` / `pbpaste` for other purposes.

Comment: @KonradRudolph this looks to be an awsome technique however... Neither Ctrl D Alt D or MetaWin D seems to work for me for exiting from the file stream input. What does special key Cmd stands for ?

Comment: @Stephane Mistake, it should have read “Ctrl”. That should definitely work on most terminal emulators to insert the end-of-file character. It definitely works on all common terminals on OS X and Linux, and, I suspect, also Windows.

Comment: @KonradRudolph thanx for the clarification. With aterm ( dunno other ) If I don't input any newline, the terminal awaits twice Ctrl-D to end the stream. If I enter a new line at the end of my Shift-Insert pasted content, Ctrl-D ends the stream alright at the first stroke.

Comment: It's actually two characters less - you have to press `q` to exit `less` :D

Comment: That's pretty clever, it's cleaner and easier to remember than using `END`.

Answer (score 10):

Sometimes you don't want the pagination that `less` does and just want the complete file so you'd use `cat`.

Answer (score 4):

I use `cat` to `grep` (multiple) files.

`cat <filename1> [<filename2> <filename3>] | grep -i "string of interest"`

I know `grep` supports filenames, but If you are grepping the same file for different search terms, editing a command where the search term is the last thing on the line is easier then having to ctrl+arrow-key back through the line.

Answer (score 4):

`cat` can be used to concat several binary files into one big one:

```
cat data.001 data.002 data.003 > bigdata.dat
```

Answer (score 3):

I use `less -FX`, which makes `less` behave like `cat` when a file can be
displayed on one screen. From the `less(1)` manpage:

```
-F or --quit-if-one-screen
       Causes less to automatically exit if the entire file can be dis-
       played on the first screen.

-X or --no-init
       Disables sending the termcap initialization and deinitialization
       strings  to  the  terminal.   This is sometimes desirable if the
       deinitialization string does something unnecessary, like  clear-
       ing the screen.
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess, because of the poularity of Unix variants now, many people don't have to administer their systems (with a vengence). When things go tits-up you might just be able to reboot and enter your system in what is called a restricted environment.

You get a command line and access to a small set of what is deemed useful commands that are small and usually statically linked. You might get vi as an editor or even the smaller ed, but not emacs or vim. You would get cat, but not less. The idea is to give you enough tools to repair your system without taking too much resources as those resources may be incorrectly configured, or all used up. the less command onder those circumstances is superfluous.

Answer (score 2):

For convenience. cat have 3 characters while more/less have 4 characters. And typing cat only require your left hand only.

Comment: Why is only using your left hand an advantage? I don't use the mouse on the terminal...

Answer (score 2):

And `less` is not pre-installed on all GNU/Linux distributions. (eg. Gentoo) `cat` is everywhere, probably.

Answer (score 2):

The `cat` stays on the screen. Everything `less` disapears.

Clarified by/for Volker Siegel:

The output of `cat` stays on the screen.
Everything shown by `less` disapears after closing.

Answer (score 1):

Piping cat through grep is useful:

```
cat <filename> | grep -i "string of interest"
```

Comment: You can use `less` the same way

Comment: Not to mention that `grep` takes a filename as an argument, or you could use redirection. The pipe is expensive.

Comment: Congratulations, you win a 'useless use of cat' award!

Comment: `grep ... < filename` Or you could even forgo the redirection, since `grep` takes a filename.

Comment: the OP doesn't state what OS is being used, so RobW's points isn't useless.  Good luck using less on Solaris 8, or HP-UX 10, or other older systems that are still in production in numerous shops.

Comment: @TimKennedy - "when you've got `less`" is in the question title...

Comment: @Chris Your definition of "expensive" must be an interesting read

Comment: @ChrisDown - thanks, mate. I missed that. :)

Comment: Upvoted. I do this regularly. If I want to grep a file multiple time for different search terms, this is easier. grep wants `grep [search term] [filename]` Therefore, it's more of a pain to edit the search term if I am using the terminal history. By piping to grep, the search term is the last thing on the line, and easier to edit.

Comment: Using pipes, it's also easier to change where things are getting piped to. If you start with `cat filename | grep pattern` it's easy to later change that to `cat filename | tail -n 1000 | grep pattern`, for example. When working on the shell I often build complicated pipe schemes like this step by step.

Comment: You can still have the ordering you want without using `cat`: `< [filename] grep [search term]` and `< filename tail -n 1000 | grep pattern`. Redirection can go pretty much anywhere on a command line.

Answer (score 1):

There can be an issue with privilege escalation, as within 'less' you can press 'v' to edit a file or '!' to send a shell command.

You might want to allow some users to view a file that can only be read by the superuser, but not allow those users to edit the file or to use superuser privileges in general. You could do this by editing '/etc/sudoers' to allow them to use 'sudo /bin/cat /etc/importantfile'. You wouldn't want to allow 'sudo /usr/bin/less /etc/importantfile', because they could use 'v' to edit the file, or use '!' to launch a shell with full superuser privileges.

Of course, the users could use 'sudo /bin/cat /etc/importantfile | less' and still use 'less', without the security risks.

Answer (score 1):

The two are different. `less` is a non-standard pager (`more` is the standard one), used for viewing text, while `cat` is a standard utility, used for concatenating any type and number of data streams into one.

They might appear to do the same thing under some circumstances, but then again, so does other utilities.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of how to show the characters on the screen, `less` can do what `cat` can do; And much more.

But there is a very good reason to use cat for some cases:
`less` is just **too complex** to throw it on very simple problems. I has so many options that it's hard to find the `cat`-related ones in the man page.

Want to show the tabs in a `Makefile`?

In `man cat`, the first option is `-A`.
The description is not helpful: `-vET`.
But the long option name sounds just right: `--show-all`.

And `cat -A Makefile` does what I need.

Now, go find that for `less`.

Answer (score 0):

Both 'less' and 'more' will work exactly like 'cat' if the output is not a terminal (tty), as to pipes and files, they will both revert to no pagination.

I think it's safe to say that 'cat' is always present on any Unix-type system you will ever find.  The presence of 'less' and/or 'more' on any system is less predictable.

In scripts therefore, if you need only a non-pagination operation, 'cat' is sure to be present wherever your script is used on a Unix-type system.

Comment: Well, it's safe to assume that `more` will be available, seeing as it's mandated by the Single Unix Specification.

Comment: Sadly, whilst it may be mandated like that, but in my experience it is not always present. It's worth noting that there are a number of Unix-like systems that don't claim to be Unix.  I think one can be fairly confident that either a `less` or a `more` will be present, but I think one can't trust a particular one, nor that it's a 'true' implementation ... often one is aliased to the other, sometimes they're a minimal lightweight version.