# Why use cat to view a file?

Tags: text-processing, cat, less

It seems that the purpose of `cat` is to concatenate several files. However, many people still use `cat` instead of `less` (or a similar program like `more`) to display a file.  See, for example, the [GNU m4 manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/m4/manual/m4-1.4.18/html_node/Command-line-files.html#Command-line-files) and the answer "[How can I display the contents of a text file on the command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86325)".

> #### Man page: less
>
> **-F or --quit-if-one-screen**
>
> Causes `less` to automatically exit if the entire file can be displayed on the first screen.
>
> **-X or --no-init**
>
> Disables sending the termcap initialization and deinitialization strings to the terminal.  This is sometimes desirable if the deinitialization string does something unnecessary, like clearing the screen.

Nowadays, is it a good practice to use `cat` to display or view a file? Why use `cat` to view a file?

This makes me think to [Useless Use Of Cat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat).

**Note:** This question is not about the differences between `less` and `more`. Moreover, it concerns the visualization of a file created earlier.

---

<sub>**According to the answers and comments**, it seems that `cat` is used beyond its use because it is easier to use than a pager (e.g. `more`, `less`...). Some people think this is an irrelevant fact (or useless) but experience shows that various subtleties pertaining to the shell may have practical consequences: [use a shell loop to process a *text* **file**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/286944), [use unquoted variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)...</sub>

<sub>Negative consequences vary in intensity. For example, `cat foo bar | less` is valid because the user concatenates two files but `cat foo | less` [is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat). In the same spirit, `cat` seems to be required in "a pipeline" although it seems that a pager like `less` works in a pipeline too (note: `less` is not suited in all cases concerning displaying, e.g. [Reading a named pipe: tail or cat?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/392754/286944)).</sub>

<sub>**See also:** [How to cat a file with "or" options](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/330387/how-to-cat-a-file-with-or-options)</sub>

Comment: If you know a file isn't that large, `cat` is easier: how many keystrokes do you need to type `cat` vs. `less -F`?

Comment: And with `cat` you can continue your work in the same terminal and the output is still visible to lookup something, copy & paste etc.

Comment: This question is going to generate a lot of personal opinion and blatant speculation, and little in the way of documented analyses or facts.  Plus lengthy back and forth in comments of things that _we already have questions and answers about_, such as https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/463102/5132 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21548/5132 .

Comment: I need an additional `-X`, otherwise I don't see anything for small files...

Comment: Making an issue of whether `cat | blah` is "correct" in general practice is just fanning the flames for another pointless FOSS Holy War.

Comment: `-X disables the termcap de-/inititialization`, so not clearing screen at the end.

Comment: Are the "many people" that you refer to the users on _this_ site?

Comment: Because cats are sooo cute   ;-)

Comment: Bad habit for me too. I wonder if using `alias cat='less'` would be a good idea to I train my brain/fingers? After all aliases are not used in scripts and most other uses at the console would fall in the "Useless uses of `cat`" category anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to assume that the "many people" in the question refers to people writing tutorials, manuals, or answers on web-sites such as this one.

When writing terminal commands in a text document, the `cat` command is commonly used to show the contents of a file.

An example of this:

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo 'hello'
```

```
$ chmod +x script.sh
```

```
$ ./script.sh
hello
```

Here, I show that I have a file called `script.sh`, what its contents is, that I'm making it executable and that I'm running it and what the result of that is.

Using `cat` in this example is just a way of "showing all one's cards", i.e. to explicitly display all the prerequisites for an example (and doing it as part of a textual representation of a terminal session).

`less` and other screen based pagers, depending on how they are used, would not necessarily give that output in the terminal.  So if I wrote

```
$ less script.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo 'hello'
```

and a user tried it by themselves, they may wonder why the text of the script appears different in their terminal and then disappears from the terminal once they closed the `less` pager (if that's the way they've configured the pager), or whether their `less` is different from the `less` used in the answer (or tutorial or whatever it may be), or if they're doing something else wrong.  Allowing for the possibility of this train of thought is counterproductive and disruptive for the user.

Using `cat` when showing an example in the terminal as text is good as it gives a fairly easy way of reproducing the *exact* same results as in the given text.  For larger files, it may be better to show the file separately, and then concentrate on how that file is *used* when writing the terminal command as text.

If you prefer to use `less`, `more`, `most`, `view`, `sublime`, or some other pager or program to view files, that's totally fine.  Go ahead and do that. But if you want to provide a reproducible text describing some workflow in the terminal, you would have to also give the user a warning that the output may differ between what they read and what they see in their own terminal, depending on what pager is used and how it's configured.

Comment: @Fólkvangr the writers of the articles/answers have no idea about the skill level of the person reading the answer. Depending on what the context is, this could be someone brand new and they don't know anything. Lot's of people just google answers and follow line by line without fully understanding. By making it easier for the audience, the writer ensures no ambiguity or further questions, like where did the text go.

Answer (score 6):

`less` is a non-standard GNU utility.

[`cat` is POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/cat.html):

> ```
>      The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7, 2018 edition
>       IEEE Std 1003.1-2017 (Revision of IEEE Std 1003.1-2008)
>            Copyright © 2001-2018 IEEE and The Open Group
> ```

---

> **NAME**
>
> cat - concatenate and print files
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> cat [-u] [file...]
> ```
>
> ...

`cat` is more likely to exist *and to have consistent behavior*.

Comment: That argument rather falls over when it turns out that [so too is `more`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/more.html).  (-:

Comment: @JdeBP True, but the question refers to `less` quite specifically, relegating `more` to a footnote - literally.  I'm also pretty sure that footnote wasn't in the original posting (edits made in the first few minutes don't show).

Comment: @JdeBP Except `more` does not have the additional functionality of `less` and still requires more keystrokes, and different commands/function keys, to do things. There are several ways to do almost EVERYTHING in *NIX. Often there is no single "correct" way of doing it (all things being equal). Now, if you need a method that does not spawn additional processes, or have other esoteric limitations, then certainly the ability to do things multiple ways is good.

Comment: The question is not asking about additional functionality, and as even M. Henle acknowledges, explicitly includes `more` in what it is asking about.  An argument that only the `cat` program in the question is standard falls over because it isn't true.  It's as simple as that.  Remember where I wrote about comment discussions that address things that we already have Q&As about?  Here you are doing it.  Read https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/333946/5132 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/340511/5132 for starters.

Comment: So, more is more standard, less is less standard, and more has more functionality than cat. but more has less functionality than less.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick all I got from that: less is more when dealing with cats.

Answer (score 3):

> is it a good practice to use cat to display or view a file?

IMO, it's neither good nor bad.

"Good practice" is whatever makes you more effective as an individual and, what is often more important, it's whatever makes you a more effective member of some team.

Your preference for what tool you use to view short text files is not likely to affect your work or, how you get along with your co-workers.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, I guess it's an "old / bad" habit. Myself, I always use cat because I do not think about less that is more suitable.
If you try to display the contents of a binary file, less asks if you agree to display it anyway and automatically paginates a text when it is long.
Cat is short to write and is easy to use for very short files that do not require paging.
Nevertheless, it is indeed intended for concatenation. In this case, used to display text, it performs a concatenation on the standard output of the file given in argument 1 and the standard input which is the default of argument 2.

Comment: I'm with you, but I don't feel there is anything "bad" about the habit. Purely a preference thing, given the other reasons that have also been listed.

Comment: @Fólkvangr: not a good idea when you need to work on a lot of systems.